# python TCP client can't connect to my TCP server

Tags: python, networking, tcp, pygame

I can run two instances of my program and connect them to each other, but when someone else at a different ip trys to connect to my server their socket fails to connect. My code doesn't have input the ip of the users computer, but has my ip(as I am going to be the only person running the server) hard coded in.

Here is the server class connect function:

```
def connect(self,host,port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.unconnected_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.unconnected_socket.bind((self.host,self.port))
    self.unconnected_socket.listen(5)
```

This is the when the program creates a game

```
self.server = server.Server()
self.server.connect(ip,port) #ip is my computer's ip address
self.serverThread = Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
self.serverThread.daemon = True
self.serverThread.start()
self.client.connect(ip,port)
```

Now here is the class client connect function:

```
def connect(self,host,port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.connect((self.host,self.port))
```

When someone on a different computer runs the program but chooses to join the game:

```
self.client.connect(ip,port)
```

I am using a slightly modified Mastermind Networking Lib - 1.5.2 from pygames.

Comment: On which host is your server listening? Ensure it is a public interface and not localhost.

Comment: Also don't forget to check firewall rules.

Comment: the hose/ip is I guess my houses' ip address not 127.0.0.1 for both the server and client. I make sure to have pythonw as an exception for the firewall.

Comment: I found out my problem was, I wasn't port forwarding from my computer for the server, and also not having the clients connect to my external ip.

Answer (score 1):

Blind guess: You are probably binding your server to the address `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`). This address cannot be reached from outbound connections.
Instead, you should be setting the host of the bound address to `socket.INADDR_ANY`